# Flappy Bird Graphics Slow

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple flappy bird game as a Java Applet. The problem I'm having is that the graphics are extremely unresponsive, typically taking 5-10 seconds to respond after the key is pressed. Also, it only responds if the key is pressed a certain number of times, around 6 or 7. I don't think it's a problem with my computer, since I'm running it on a high-specs MacBook Pro (8 GB RAM, i5 processor). Here's the two main classes I use:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
//The main class I use to run the game
public class Flap extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
 final int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 500;
 Thread thread;
 Bird b;
 boolean beenPressed = false;
 public void init()
 {
     this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

     this.addKeyListener(this);
     b = new Bird();
     thread = new Thread(this);
     thread.start();
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
     g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
     g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT - 100);
     g.setColor(Color.green);
     g.fillRect(0, 400, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     b.draw(g);
 }

 public void update(Graphics g)
 {
     paint(g);
 }

@Override
 public void run() 
 {
    for(;;)
    {
        //Pillar upPillar = new Pillar()
        b.move();
        repaint();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        if(!beenPressed)
        {
            b.setUp(true);
        }
        beenPressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        b.setDown(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        beenPressed = false;
        b.setUp(false);
    }
    else
    {
        b.setDown(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) 
{

}
}


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
//The Bird class, which has the methods for the player to move 
public class Bird 
{
 int x, y, yvel;
 boolean goingUp, goingDown;
 public Bird()
 {
  x = 200;
  y = 200;
 }

 public void draw(Graphics g)
 {
     g.setColor(Color.yellow);
     g.fillRect(x, y, 60, 25);
 }

 public void move()
 {
     if(goingUp)
     {
         yvel -= 50;
     }
     else if(goingDown)
     {
         yvel += 50;
     }
     y += yvel;
 }

 public int getX()
 {
     return x;
 }

 public int getY()
 {
     return y;
 }

 public void setUp(boolean b)
 { 
     goingUp = b;
 }

 public void setDown(boolean b)
 {
     goingDown = b;
 }
}
```

It's still unfinished, but at this stage, I think the bird should at least be moving.

Comment: Using applets, bad idea. Applets are deprecated and a dead technology.  `Applet` is also not double buffered, so you're probably going to end up with some horrible flashing going on.  `KeyListener` is will known for having issues (not responding), while it's the only solution when using AWT, the ket bindings API is a better solution when using Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok, what do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest, is having a look at using a `JPanel` as your base component and then have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works

Comment: @MadProgrammer alright, thanks. I'll check it out

Comment: If you "really" need high performance (or just want more control over the painting process), you should also have a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll check those out too.

Comment: You might also want to explore [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) which generally has a better API geared towards this type of thing

Comment: I think the "core" issue is that fact that the time between updates is to long, it allows for the key to be pressed and released before an update cycle occurs.  Try setting `Thread.sleep(500)` to something more like `Thread.sleep(100)` and see if that improves you performance.  It would be unreasonable to use a value of `5` or `10`, but you're going to need to play around with the amount of the delta applied to the object

Comment: You’re only updating the position every half second.if you’re press a key and release it again before the current thread’sleep conpletes, nothing will happen. Keep the key down for half a second and your bird should be moving. Better change your y directly as a result of the key press or think of another approach.

Answer (score 3):

The graphics isn't slow, the time between updates is to large.  It basically allows for the key to be pressed and released before a update cycle takes place.

I would reduce `Thread.sleep(500);` to something more like `Thread.sleep(10);` and change the movement delta to something more like...

```
public void move()
 {
     if(goingUp)
     {
         yvel -= 1;
     }
     else if(goingDown)
     {
         yvel += 1;
     }
     y += yvel;
 }
```

as a starting point.

## Recommendations...

Using applets, bad idea. Applets are deprecated and a dead technology. Applet is also not double buffered, so you're probably going to end up with some horrible flashing going on. KeyListener is will known for having issues (not responding), while it's the only solution when using AWT, the ket bindings API is a better solution when using Swing

The first thing I would suggest, is having a look at using a JPanel as your base component and then have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works

If you "really" need high performance (or just want more control over the painting process), you should also have a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

I'd also recommend having a look at [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) which has better APIs for this kind of thing